# Implementing Linear Regression using Gradient Descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I have just started in machine learning and currently taking the course by andrew Ng's Machine learning Course. I have implemented the linear regression algorithm in python but the result is not desirable. I code of python is as follows:

```
import numpy as np

x = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]]
y = [10,16,20,23,29,30,35,40,45,50]

x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

theta = np.zeros((2,1))

def Cost(x,y,theta):
    m = len(y)
    pred_ions = np.transpose(theta).dot(x)
    J = 1/(2*m) * np.sum((pred_ions - y)*(pred_ions - y))
    return J

def GradientDescent(x,y,theta,iteration,alpha):
    m = len(y)
    pred_ions = np.transpose(theta).dot(x)
    i = 1
    while i <= iteration:
        theta[0] = theta[0] - alpha/m * np.sum(pred_ions - y)
        theta[1] = theta[1] - alpha/m * np.sum((pred_ions - y)*x[1,:])
        Cost_History = Cost(x,y,theta)
        i = i + 1

    return theta[0],theta[1]
itera = 1000
alpha = 0.01
a,b = GradientDescent(x,y,theta,itera, alpha)
print(a)
print(b)
```

I am not able to figure out what exactly is the problem. But, my results are something very strange. The value of parameter is, according to above code, are  298 and 19890. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), especially #1. What is the script supposed to do? Why is the result not "desirable"? What do you suspect the underlying problem is?

Answer (score 1):

Ah. I did this assignment too a while ago.

See this mentioned in Page 7 of the assignment PDF:

> Octave/MATLAB array indices start from one, not zero. If you’re
>   storing θ0 and θ1 in a vector called theta, the values will be
>   theta(1) and theta(2).

So, in your while loop, change the `theta[0]` and `theta[1]` to `theta[1]` and `theta[2]`. It should work right.

Also, if you are storing the Cost in Cost_History, shouldn't it include the iteration variable like

```
Cost_History[i] = Cost(x,y,theta)
```

Just check that too! Hope this helped.

*Edit 1:* Okay, I have understood the issue now. In his video, Andrew Ng says that you need to update both the thetas **simultaneously.** To do that, store the theta matrix in a temp variable. And update theta[0] and theta[1] based on the temp values.

Currently in your code, during `theta[1] =` it has changed the `theta[0]` to the newer value already, so both are not being updated simultaneously.

So instead, do this:

```
while i <= iteration:
    temp = theta
    theta[0] = theta[0] - alpha/m * np.sum(np.transpose(temp).dot(x) - y)
    theta[1] = theta[1] - alpha/m * np.sum((np.transpose(temp).dot(x) - y)*x[1,:])
    Cost_History[i] = Cost(x,y,theta)
    i = i + 1
```

It should work now, if not, let me know, I will debug on my side.

Comment: I am doing these assignments in Python not MATLAB/OCTAVE and in python array, indices start from 0 not 1. Thanks for your reply. The point of cost history makes sense to me.

Comment: @user8125394 Oh I see. I think I have found the issue after delving a little deeper. Check my updated answer and let me know if it works now.